# Can setOrganizationId in Android 12 be kept Public

Tags: android

The New Android 12 provided increased privacy to users accessing the application by not providing an IMEI. But an alternative that can be used by an app developer is to uniquely identify a device that has enrolled in a work profile.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager#setOrganizationId(java.lang.String)

How can we securely transmit OrganizationId if it is sensitive and the app requires it before authentication?

Comment: What makes you believe that the Enterprise ID is sensitive?

Comment: If enterprise id is leaked, an adversary could host an application to generate device ID and leak the same.

Comment: An attacker would only be able to generate an enrollment-specific ID, which is like a device ID, just for this organization.